# How to prevent the back button from returning previous page

Tags: flutter

How do I prevent a user from going back to a previous page.

For example I have `page 1, page 2, submission successful`,

I noticed even if I don't include a back button and the user tries to use the the device back button/gesture, the previous screen is displayed to the user.

How do I make it that when the user tries to use his device back button or swipe guesture he is sent to screen `page 1` and not `page 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For disabling the back button you can wrap your widget with WillPopScope.

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  return WillPopScope( 
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: .....
  ); 
}
```

For swipe animation you can wrap the widget with [GesturedDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and switch the tab.

```
GestureDetector( 
  onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _onHorizontalDrag(details), 
  child: Container(),
 )
```

Another option is [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html). Example of PageView.builder implementation is:

```
PageView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, position) { 
    return _buildPage();
  },
  itemCount: listItemCount, 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WillPopScope widget

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => Future.value(false); 
        child: // The rest of your code here
 )}
```

This will prevent it from navigating back using the android back button.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is calling the `pushReplacement` method of your `Navigator` instead of `push`. This way, you remove the old route from the stack, replacing it by the new route.